# Getting blank page on displaying fragment inside a fragment?

Tags: android

This is my fragment which is in navigation menu.

```
class MirandaFragment extends Fragment {
    protected View view;
    FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.miranda, container, false);
        ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        adapterViewPager = new MyPageAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);


        return view;
    }
}
```

This is the adapter where I has set two fragments EngMiranda and SpaMiranda.

```
class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

// Returns total number of pages.
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_ITEMS;
}

// Returns the fragment to display for a particular page.
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return EngMiranda.newInstance("Fragment 1", getCount());
        case 1:
            return SpaMiranda.newInstance("Fragment 2", getCount());
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

// Returns the page title for the top indicator
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "English";
        case 1:
            return "Spanish";
        default:
            return null;
    }

}
```

}

After app gets open for first time then I am able to open the fragment and view the tab fragments in it but when we open that fragment for second time then adapter is not displaying.

Comment: What does your onCreate() method look like? Write System.out.statements on your onCreate(), onActivityCreated(), onAttached(), onDetach(), onDestroy() methods and see what gets called. You know that onCreate doesn't always get called, if you only hit the home button. It does get called if you hit the back button.

Comment: I am not getting which method will call back when fragment is backpressed and opened again can you please help me with this.

Comment: Did you perhaps setRetainInstance(true) in any of your fragments? Fragments have callbacks onCreate(), onActivityCreated(), onAttached(), onDetach(), onDestroy(). I believe you are counting on one of them to be called and it is not being called. Try overriding each of them and puting a System.out.println("at OnAttached") line in each to see if they are being called. You should definitely put one in onCreateView(), see if it is being called when your app reopens.

Comment: Don't forget to call super on an overridden method.